# Spring cacheEvict based on like search

Tags: spring, caching, spring-cache

I am caching some object using Spring cache implementation, the underline cache is EhCache. I am trying to evict the cache based on wildcard search for the keys,the reason is the way I stored them and I only know the partial key. Hence I wanted to do something like below. I did search this forum for relevant answer but did not find any.

```
@CacheEvict(beforeInvocation=true, key="userId+%")
public User getUser(String userId)
{
  //some implementation
}
```

Now if I try this I get an error for the SPEL. Also I tried to create a custom keygenerator for this, here the eviction works if the key generator returns one key, but I have a couple of keys based on my search.

```
@CacheEvict(beforeInvocation=true, keyGenerator="cacheKeyEvictor")
public User getUser(String userId)
{
  //some implementation
}

//Custom key generator for eviction
public class cacheKeyEvictor implements KeyGenerator {

  @Override
  public Object generate(Object arg0, Method arg1, Object... arg2) {

      //loop the cache and do a like search and return the keys
      return object; //works if I send one key. Won't work for a list of keys
  }
}
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Could someone please help with this question?

Comment: I am trying to extend the KeyGenerator class and evict the cache I need, this way I will achieve what I want but nit sure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: you can't evict a list of configurable keys. This feature doesn't exist.